# Problem with getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

Following code is causing the problem:

```
var CheckBoxes = document.getElementsByClassName('DeleteCheckBox')

for (var i = 0; i < CheckBoxes.length; i++) {
    CheckBoxes[i].checked = false;        
}
```

Well, the checkboxes are still selected after this runs. And it runs, because I checked the i variable and it is counting.

What is wrong here? By the way, only checkboxes have the "DeleteCheckBox" class, so only checkboxes get returned by getElementsByClassName.

SOLVED:

I've found the problem. I am using asp.net and the framework seems to assign the class to the "label" (it creates a span tag) of the checkbox, not to the input.

Fixed with InputAttributes.Add("class", "DeleteCheckBox"); (asp.net codebehind)

Comment: It looks like it should work - are you sure the problem is with getElementsByClassname()? Does it work if you use document.getElementsByTagName('input')?

Comment: Can you _demonstrate_ this "not working"?

Comment: Well, the checkboxes are still selected...

Comment: Yes, it works by using document.getElementsByTagName('input')

Comment: Works fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/5E8Wd/2/

Comment: What browser? Is it supported by your specific browser? http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/05/getelementsbycl.html

Comment: I made a jsfiddle of this: http://jsfiddle.net/v8F4y/ . and it works fine in Chrome. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Is `getElementsByClassName` defined in the first place? Are you using a recent enough browser or do you have a replacement function?

Comment: Oh, I think I've found the problem. I am using asp.net and the framework seems to assign the class to the "label" of the checkbox, not the input portion of it..

Comment: @Peter Siegmann that really makes no sense. Do a "view source" on your page and look at what the browser is actually seeing.

Comment: It makes sense, see:

http://forums.asp.net/p/541142/541562.aspx

Comment: No, it really does not make sense. Have you done a "view source" yet?

Comment: Yea, and it works now with InputAttributes in the codebehind.

Read the link, asp.net creates a span around the checkbox and assigns the css class to it. That caused the failure.

Comment: I see what you mean now - you didn't mean the "label" *attribute*, you meant another element :-)  Well in any case "view source" is always a good thing to check!  Glad it works now!

Answer (score 1):

Your code is perfectly fine. On the webpage, right click and check the source. If you don't see `<input type="checkbox" class="DeleteCheckBox" ...>` then you are looking at the wrong place. Your JS code assumes that the class DeleteCheckBox is applied to the checkboxes. Fix your markup.

Answer (score 0):

Well if you had copy pasted the code : ';' is missing on - suggest you use to console.log to check where problem lies [whether the code infact runs or are their errors while selecting].

Comment: The semicolon missing from the end of the first line would not be the cause of any problems due to [semicolon insertion](http://inimino.org/~inimino/blog/javascript_semicolons).

Answer (score -1):

I'm taking a stab at this, as I don't have time to write a full demo.  getElementsByClassName creates something called a HTMLcollection.  HTML collections are live lists, which means everytime you access them they rerun the query that you used to generate the collection.

Everytime you update the checked property the getElementsByClassName is run and a new collection is generated.  So if there were 10 input boxes, you remove one with this class there are now 9, and the variable updates to 9.  If you change this to getElementsByTagName('input') this method will work, because when the query is rerun nothing changes.  However, you probably don't want to hit every input on the page.  Also, the performance will still be awful due to the way you structured your loop.

Read more here
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/HTMLCollection

Here's how to refactor and make this run 1000% faster and it should 'work' as you are expecting

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('DeleteCheckBox'),
    l = inputs.length;
while( l-- ) {
  inputs[ l ].checked = false;        
}
```

On each iteration the inputs variable will get updated to a new number, but since you are counting down this should be fine.

Comment: This is totally incorrect. The list is in no sense "live" in the way you describe.

Comment: You're lucky you're caching the value, then changing the cached value. Otherwise, it wouldn't work because `inputs.length` doesn't change (because the nodes don't go anywhere).

Comment: The *HTMLcollection* does change, the value l doesn't change b/c it's cached and inputs.length doesn't change b/c I'm not removing the className.  However, getElementsByClassName is indeed being run every iteration of this loop b/c inputs is being accessed.  Here is a demo for you two to review http://jsfiddle.net/RWXp6/

Comment: You should at least read the spec before voting down answers.